# HQL Query syntax in grails

Tags: sql, grails, hql

I am trying to get a list of employees that have multiple "Education" which each have an "Education type"

so Employee has a collection of educations, which each have an type which have a name.

```
    def unchecked = educationTypes?.unchecked
    String query = "FROM Employee e, IN (e.education)  AS ed WHERE ed.type.name IN (:typeNames)";

    def matches = Employee.executeQuery(query, [typeNames: unchecked]);
```

The query above give me the following:

```
Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ed near line 1, column 39 [FROM Employee e, IN (e.education)  AS ed WHERE ed.type.name IN (:typeNames)]
    at $Proxy12.createQuery(Unknown Source)
```

So I am trying to figure out how to access this correctly. Much appreciation for any help

Comment: Is unchecked empty?  I think in clauses break in HQL if your parameter is empty (at least I've run into that problem in the past, but I can't remember the exception).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Employee.executeQuery("""
    select e from Employee e, Education ed 
    where ed.employee = e and ed.type.name IN (:typeNames)
""", [typeNames: [...]])
```